# php variable issue in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

i want to generate loop of javascript in php which give me syntax error.here is what i want

```
var d1 = [
          [(new Date("01/06/2013")). getTime(),4],
          [(new Date("01/07/2013")). getTime(),0],
         ];
```

i want to make it dynamic from db.here is what i tried

```
var d1 = [
<?php
    while($rw = $oAppl->row($res))
    {
        $php_var = $rw['list_date_rent'];
        $php_var2 = $rw['rntval'];
?>            
    var php_var = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";
    var php_var2 = "<?php echo $php_var2; ?>";
    [(new Date("+'"php_var"'+")). getTime(),php_var2],
<?php
    }
?>
];
```

Comment: No you do NOT want a trailing comma!!! and where is the echo?

Comment: @mplungjan actually Javascript array literals are tolerant of trailing commas, although object literals aren't.

Comment: Trailing commas will fail in IE

Comment: By the way...that's not a valid cross-browser JavaScript date.

Comment: @mplungjan:before i echo it to a js var..so no need to echo again

Comment: @mplungjan `[1,2,3,]` works fine for me down to IE8, don't have anything lower to test in.

Comment: @DaveRandom You can use IE7 compatible mode to test that behaviour  afaik.

Comment: @DaveRandom try this javascript:alert([1,2,3,].length) - it is 4 long

Comment: @mplungjan That's not exactly the same as a syntax error though ;-) Hmm, I'm starting to wonder whether this is only an issue with object literals.

Comment: @mplungjan Oh you're right. M$ spec violations strike again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using the javascript variables ?

```
var d1 = [
<?php while($rw = $oAppl->row($res)) { ?>
  [(new Date("<?php echo $rw['list_date_rent']; ?>")). getTime(),<?php echo $rw['rntval']; ?>],
<?php } ?>
     ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT want a trailing comma and you need to either echo the complete thing or split your echo into two - this is perhaps more readable

```
var d1 = [];
  <?php
    $first = true;
    while($rw = $oAppl->row($res)) {     
      if (!$first) echo ","; else $first=false; ?>
      d1.push([ 
        new Date("<?php echo $rw['list_date_rent']; ?>").getTime(),
        <?php echo $rw['rntval']?>
      ]);
   <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just build the array in PHP and then use `json_encode` to output it into javascript?

```
$results = array();
while ($rw = $oAppl->row($res)) {
    $results[] = array(
        'new Date("' . $rw['list_date_rent'] , '").getTime()',
        $rw['rntval']
    );
}

?>
var d1 = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
```

Comment: You can't `json_encode()` code and expect it to be executed, it will become a string literal. However, you could just do the calculation in PHP and put that in the array instead, it's always going to be `strtotime($rw['list_date_rent']) * 1000`.

Comment: @DaveRandom Of course you can't get the code to execute in javascript.  What I did is formatted his data in the format he requested.  Where do you see anything about strtotime or 1000?  The OP is not saying anything about the source of the data, simply that he needs to take it from a specific place.

Comment: Think about the actual data structure that would result from his sample output. The first key of the child array is a UNIX timestamp of the date string with milliseconds. This code would not produce the same data structure, the first element of the child array would be a string with code in it.

Comment: @DaveRandom Fair enough; the question though is whether this is php code or JavaScript code.  If the resulting output contains javascript code there's no reason why it wouldn't execute correctly.

Comment: ...but this doesn't produce executable Javascript code. It produces a Javascript string with some code in it. It won't be executed.